# Second derivative of $e^{-\frac 1{x(1-x)}}$ at $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis

> Define $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ by $$f(x)=\left\lbrace\matrix {e^{-\frac
>  1{x(1-x)}} & \text{if $0<x<1$}\\  0\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ &
>  \text{otherwise}\hfill} \right.$$ Show that $f''(0)$ exists and find
>   its value.

This is a bonus question that was given on a recent quiz and I can't figure out how to do it. It doesn't seem like we're supposed to actually take the derivative of the equation three times, because that would take forever. Could someone maybe walk me through it? I'm pretty sure it'll show up on an exam.

Comment: Note they're asking for $f''(x)$, the second derivative. What techniques do you know? Know about Taylor expansions?

Comment: @Kaynex Looking at the exponent in the question, I don't think a Taylor series is applicable here.

Comment: You're right about the second derivative. I didn't notice, but that makes the problem a lot easier. In similar questions, [this](http://www.csun.edu/~panferov/math350/m350_mt2_s_su15.pdf) is how the professor does it. It's the very last problem.

Comment: Please use MathJax (see the edit for a sample of code) for facilitating research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Prove by induction that the $n$-th derivative of $f$ is of the form
$$f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{P_n(x)}{Q_n(x)}f(x)$$
where $P_n$ and $Q_n$ are polynomials whose coefficients depend on $n$.

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused: how do we determine those polynomials?

Comment: @Kelly You absolutely don't have to, that's the beauty of this method. All you need to know is that the derivative of a polynomial is another polynomial. Or if you wish, the induction will show that there is a recursive formula to compute them, but you don't really need to know  what the coefficients are.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Then do you suggest to conclude showing that the limit for $f''(x)$ at $x=0$ exists I guess.

Comment: @gimusi yes, one concludes that $f$ is infinitely differentiable on $(0,1)$ and all derivatives have limit $0$ at $x=0$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier If the second derivative has (x^4) as the denominator, then doesn't it imply that f(x) isn't continuous at x=0?

Comment: @Kelly No, because of the exponential: it tends to $0$ faster than any power of $x$. This is why you don't need to know explicitly the $P_n$ and $Q_n$: the limit will be $0$ because of $e^{-\frac 1x}$ no matter what they are.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Okay, I think 'm getting it. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Kelly You're welcome!

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Thanks, to conclude formally do you suggest to use MVT or l'Hospital?

Comment: @gimusi L'Hospital is usually efficient to get compared growth results. Here you can make the change of variables $u=\frac 1{x(1-x)}$ (note that the rational function, $\frac {P_n(x)}{Q_n(x)}$, stays a rational function of $u$, say $\frac {A(u)}{B(u)}$), and apply l'Hospital repeatedly to $\frac{A(u)}{e^u}$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

We know that

- $\lim_{x\to 0^-} f''(x)=0$

what about

- $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f''(x)=?$

Comment: @gimusi So the second derivative of the function is -\dfrac{\left(2x-1\right)\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x+1}{x}}}{x^4}
 Doesn't that mean that it isn't defined as x --> 0?  edit: Sorry, I'm only just beginning on the site and apparently LaTex formatting is incompatible.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Sorry, why it is not defined? Isn't it equal to 0?

Comment: @gimusi Yes, it seems so. However the OP was asking for a way to not have to compute the derivatives.

Comment: @gimusi I just wasn't sure if computing the derivative was the right way to go. I thought it was not defined because of the 0 in the denominator.

Comment: @Kelly You can use the hint from Arnaud Mortier